# rollup not reading development environment variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, rollup

I'm trying to build a rollup package but i need to use environment variables for development and production

when I run my build scripts it only reads the environment variables when it normal .env or .env.local

here's my build script:

"build-rollup:development": "env-cmd -f ./.env.development .env.development && rollup -c"

I have my environment variables in the root directory.